# How can I set the width of a React.Image component and make the height automatically scale to maintain aspect ratio?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styles

How can I set the width of a React.Image component and make the height automatically scale to maintain aspect ratio? I have tried setting height to auto like this...

```
imageStyle: {
    width: 400,
    height: 'auto'
}
```

I have also tried setting height to 0 and not setting height at all. All of these approaches made the image not display. I think the height may be set to 0 by default.

I have also played with flexbox, setting the style of the image container component to have flexDirection: 'row' and giving the image flex: 1. This displayed the image as desired with the specified width and a properly scaled height. However, this interferes with zoom functionality elsewhere in the component. Is there another style approach that works?

Btw, this only occurs when setting width. It is straightforward to set image height and make width automatically scale to maintain aspect ratio. In that case, this style works...

```
imageStyle: {
    height: 400,
}
```

Comment: what is the unit? `400px`??

Comment: I don't think the unit is important, but I could be wrong. In my particular case, it is set to a constant called SCREEN_WIDTH where SCREEN_WIDTH is defined as const SCREEN_WIDTH = React.Dimensions.get('screen').width 

I just used 400px here as a simplified code chunk.

Comment: in general setting width of an image would change the height automatically.it is not tied to any framework.one way to test is to put the image element in a div and set the image width to 100% and change the div width. see that works

Answer (score 0):

The [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image) library is a good pick for this issue.

It provides

> an  component which scales width or height automatically to keep the aspect ratio. It is useful when you don't know the aspect ratio in advance (e.g. user-uploaded content) but want to display the entire image and **limit it only by width or height** to fit the container component.

Example usage is as follows.

```js
const image = (
   <Image
       width={Dimensions.get('window').width} // height will be calculated automatically
       source={{uri: '<image uri>'}}
   />
);
```